# How can I automatically log warnings and errors from the console in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, electron

I'd like to log these automatically generated errors and warnings in my application so I can debug issues my users have, but thus far I've not been able to find a solution for logging these. Does anyone know of a package or method?

Thank you.

Comment: See this blog post: https://blog.sentry.io/2016/01/04/client-javascript-reporting-window-onerror.html They also offer a service that will do it for you https://sentry.io/welcome/

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to listen for errors by subscribing to `window.onerror`:

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
  // log to your server

  return false;
}
```

But some browsers don't always provide you with a stacktrace, so you have to wrap functions calls that are at the top of the stack chain with a `try` `catch` :

```
function wrapErrors(fn) {
  // don't wrap function more than once
  if (!fn.__wrapped__) {
    fn.__wrapped__ = function () {
          try {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
      } catch (e) {
        logErrorToYourServer(e); // report the error
        throw e; // re-throw the error
      }
    };
  }

  return fn.__wrapped__;
}

var invoke = wrapErrors(function(obj, method, args) {
  return obj[method].apply(this, args);
});

invoke(Math, 'highest', [1, 2]); // no method Math.highest
```

This function has to be called:

- At the start of your application (e.g. in $(document).ready if you use jQuery)
- In event handlers, e.g. addEventListener or $.fn.click
- Timer-based callbacks, e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame

For example:

```
$(wrapErrors(function () { // application start
  doSynchronousStuff1(); // doesn't need to be wrapped

  setTimeout(wrapErrors(function () {
    doSynchronousStuff2(); // doesn't need to be wrapped
  });

  $('.foo').click(wrapErrors(function () {
    doSynchronousStuff3(); // doesn't need to be wrapped
  });
}));
```

(code shamelessly copied from [sentry's blog post](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/01/04/client-javascript-reporting-window-onerror.html))

You can find more information in the following links:

- [GlobalEventHandlers.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)
- [sentry's blog post](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/01/04/client-javascript-reporting-window-onerror.html)
- [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/pmuellr/854959) on how to overwrite AddEventListener

There are also commercial products

- [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) that is also open source
- [TrackJs](https://trackjs.com)